# Undefind is not an object (evaluating 'state.productsBasket.concat')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I got an error "undefind is not an object (evaluating 'state.productsBasket.concat')". I want to add all products, what names I click to the array productsBasket: [].
Here is my action:

```
export const addToBasket = (name) => {
 return {
   type: "BASKET",
   payload: name,
 };
}
```

Here is my reducer:

```
const defaultState = {
  products: [{

      id: 1,
      author: "notCurrentUser",
      price: "200$",
      type: "Phone",
      name: "Redmi 8a",
      img: "https://i01.appmifile.com/webfile/globalimg/gaoruijia/Phone/C3K-red.png",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      author: "notCurrentUser",
      price: "350$",
      type: "Phone",
      name: "Note 10",
      img: "https://www.sunrise.ch/en/kmu/geraete/handys/samsung-galaxy-note10-plus-5g.primaryproductimage.code-MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDIwMDAx.format-hardware-configurator-l.png",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      author: "notCurrentUser",
      price: "1000$",
      type: "Phone",
      name: "IPhone XS",
      img: "https://mimelon.com/uploads/catalog/Product//iphone-xs-max-space-select-2018.png",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      price: "1000$",
      author: "currentUser",
      type: "Laptop",
      name: "DELL 12",
      img: "https://i.dell.com/sites/csimages/Video_Imagery/all/xps_7590_touch.png",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      price: "1000$",
      author: "currentUser",
      type: "Laptop",
      name: "OMEN V15",
      img: "https://46c4ts1tskv22sdav81j9c69-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/prod/sites/2/2020/06/be8d761951928ac75b583b8e687ae493-scaled.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      price: "1000$",
      author: "currentUser",
      basket: "hello",
      type: "Phone",
      name: "ds",
      img: "https://mimelon.com/uploads/catalog/Product//iphone-xs-max-space-select-2018.png",
    }
  ],
  productsBasket: [],
}


const allRec = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "PRODUCT_SELECTED":
      return action.payload;
      break;
    case "BASKET":

      return {...state,
      productsBasket: state.productsBasket.concat({
        name: action.payload
      })
    };
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  };
}
export default allRec;
```

I add a product in ProductDetails component in a row:

```
  <Text onPress={() => dispatch(addToBasket(product))} style={styles.name}>{product.name}</Text>
```

Here is the full code of ProductDetails (without styles):

```
import React, { Component, useCallback } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
} from 'react-native'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { addToBasket } from '../actions/actions.js'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

function ProductDetails({ navigation }) {
   const product = useSelector(state => state.active);
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
  

   const handler = useCallback((pName) => {
      dispatch(addToBasket(pName));
    }, [product]);
  if (!product) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Выберите товар</Text>
      </View>
    );
  } else
   return (

     <View style={styles.productDetailsContainer}>
       <Image
          style={styles.productImg}
          source={{
            uri: product.img,
          }}
        />
        <View styles={styles.row}>
          <View>
            <Text onPress={() => dispatch(addToBasket(product))} style={styles.name}>{product.name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.price}>{product.price}</Text>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.flexEnd} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Basket')}>В корзину</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
   );
 }
export default ProductDetails;
```

Here is my Basket component(I want to show all products, added to productsBasket: [] here:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
class Basket extends Component {
render() {
   const showProductsList = (type, maxlength) => {

     return this.props.products.map ((product) => {
         return (
             <View key={product.key}>
             <Image
               source={{
                 uri: product.img,
               }}
             />
               <View>
                 <Text>{product.name}</Text>
                 <Text>Price: {product.price}</Text>
               </View>
             </View>
         );
     })

   }
   if (!this.props.products) {
     return (
       <View>
         <Text>Выберите товар</Text>
       </View>
     );
   } else {
   return (
     <View>
      {showProductsList(true, 4)}
     </View>
   )
}
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    products: state.active.productsBasket
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Basket);
```

I also leave products-order components here:

```
import React, {Component, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { select } from '../actions/index.js'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback
} from 'react-native';

class ProductsList extends Component {
  showTelephonesList (type, maxlength) {

    var currentLength = 0;
    return this.props.products.map ((product) => {
      if(product.type == type & currentLength < maxlength) {
        currentLength += 1;
        return (
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={product.id} onPressIn={() => this.props.nav.navigate('ProductDetails')} onPress={() => this.props.select(product)}>
            <View key={product.id} style={styles.product}>
            <Image
              style={styles.productImg}
              source={{
                uri: product.img,
              }}
            />
              <View style={styles.textView}>
                <Text style={styles.textName}>{product.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textPrice} >Price: {product.price}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
      }
    })

  }
  render() {
     return (
       <View>
        <ScrollView>
          <View styles={styles.productsName}>
          <Text name={this.props.type}
            style={styles.productsText}
            title={this.props.type}
            onPress={() => this.props.nav.navigate('MoreProducts',
            {tip: this.props.type})}>
            {this.props.type + "s ->"}
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.productsContainer}>
              {this.showTelephonesList(this.props.type, this.props.length)}
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
     );
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    products: state.products,
  };
}
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({select: select}, dispatch)
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  productsContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    width: "100%",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
  product: {
    width: "45%",
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
    textAlign: "left",
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  textPrice: {
    alignSelf: "flex-start",
    fontSize: 15,
  },
  productsText: {
    fontSize: 25,
    marginLeft: "5%",
  },
  textName: {
    alignSelf: "flex-start",
  },
  productImg: {
   width: 180,
   height: 180,
 },
 productsName: {
   marginTop: "50px",
 },
 textView: {
   textAlign: "left",
   width: "100%",
   padding: 10,
 }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(ProductsList);
```

I use product order component in WebPage component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native'
import ProductsList from '../containers/products-order'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
function WebPage({ navigation }) {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
       <ProductsList nav={navigation} type={"Phone"} length={2} />
       <ProductsList nav={navigation} type={"Laptop"} length={2} />
      </ScrollView>
     </View>
   )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#F2F2F2",
  },
});

export default WebPage;
```

Comment: From a glance at your reducer, the only way this could happen is if you dispatched an action of type `"PRODUCT_SELECTED"`, whole payload is not an object of the expected shape (in particular, one that is missing the `productsBasket`). Since it doesn't appear that you use that action anywhere in the code you've shown us, I can't say more than that.

Comment: Hi, Robin. "PRODUCT_SELECTED" is working well, i tested it. I am sure, that the problem is in productBasket

Comment: @Shinigami Check redux devtools, state.productsBasket [is undefined](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-in-javascript#:~:text=The%20%E2%80%9CTypeError%3A%20'undefined',shown%20only%20on%20safari%20browser.)

Comment: Hi, i use react native, so i don't know how to use redux devtools on mobile. "state.productsBasket is undefined" Yes, you true, but why does it show an error? How can I fix it?

Comment: can you share examples of where you use the `PRODUCT_SELECTED` action type, and in particular what the payload is? It seems certain, from what you've shared so far, that no matter how "well" you think this action is working, it leaves the state in a shape with no `productsBasket`.

Comment: Ok, i left the code of product-order component, where i use PRODUCT_SELECTED